# Next.js stylesheet is not loaded

Tags: html, reactjs, web, next.js

I'm using Next.js to build my website. I modify the server using express.js server so I have `server.js` on my root folder of my project.

When I started the server `npm run dev` which run `node server.js`, my home page renders correctly. But when I navigate to some of other page in my website, the css is not loaded. But if I refresh the page, it will load the css and the problem is gone

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({dev})
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on port ${port}...`)
  })
})
```

Here's my `server.js` file. I think there is no problem with the code.
I use @zeit/next-less package for compiling my LESS stylesheet
Please help

Thanks

Comment: Check where the compiled css is being saved.

Comment: The documentation said that the compiled LESS file is compiled to `.next/static/style.css`

Comment: I don't have any experience with express.js servers, but if the file exists in ```.next/static/style.css``` then I think it's probably the link path which is not correct. Check that the js file is addressed correctly. But you said that it does not load correctly on "some of other page in my website". Please explain on which pages it doesn't work on and maybe their source code would be helpful.

Comment: The weird thing is, I have tried to upload the website to docker and to elastic beanstalk. And the production version load the css correctly -,-

Comment: So what is the problem then?

Comment: This thread is no longer a problem. I created this thread before I deployed my app to production. Now its fine, as long as the production's stylesheet is loaded. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/282

In short as a workaround:

1. Create an empty CSS file in /static/ directory.
2. Import it in _app.js:

```js
import '../static/jank-empty.css';
```

I hope that it would help.

Comment: did the trick for me, I had to add _app.js from here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

And then restart dev server so it sees it

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the nextjs wasn't loading the rel=stylesheet link tags. It was only able to load rel=preload link tags.
so I did a workaround like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='preload'][as='style']").forEach(link => link.rel = "stylesheet")
```